# Showing indeterminate progress in Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i`m trying to show indeterminate progress bar in ABS v. 4.0.2 by following code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
}
```

on ICS virtual device it works fine, but progress do not shows in device with Android 2.1.
what i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Make sure you import `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window`, not `android.view.Window`.

Comment: Is it possible to make the progress horizontal ?

Answer (score 17):

Try `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)` to get backward compatibility.

Comment: Maybe this is related to an issue: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/449

Answer (score 7):

do this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.section_one1);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

on anything clickable like starting an activity via intent or adapters or whatever
show your progressbar on click

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

but using this method when the user goes back to the activity the progress dialog will be visible still. There are many ways to stop it but the easiest one is just to use

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    { 
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```