# Setting setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate in SherlockFragments with SherlockActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using Jake's ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator.
I realized I can't set `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate` in SherlockFragments with SherlockActivity.

In SherlockActivity, I have

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
    }
```

And in my SherlockFragment's **Asynctask**

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
            getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
            getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
        }
```

The progressbar does not appear. Any reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [Showing indeterminate progress in Sherlock Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10615994)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` to make the indeterminate progress bar show.