# Android - Changing order of dialogs

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-dialog

In my application I am using a navigation drawer. When the application is launched for the first time, a dialog is shown to the user to explain the usage of navigation drawer while an activity continues to load in the background. My activity utilizes the progress dialog to show a loading message and spinner while the data is loading.

Now the issue is, when the user launches the app for the first time, the dialog for the navigation drawer opens up and the progress dialog open on top of that. Is there a way in which i can reorder the dialog placement so that the progress dialog goes behind the other dialog which is showing info of the navigation drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the original question: If you open the dialog for the explanation last (that is, call `show()` on it last), it will overlap the progress-dialog.

---

However, since you're using modern Android UI-components, might as well do it a little more "sexy":

The [Android Style Guide for Application Drawers](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction) reads:

> #### Introduce the user to the drawer at first use
>
> **Upon first launch of your app, introduce the user to the navigation drawer by automatically opening it.** This ensures that users know
>   about the navigation drawer and prompts them to learn about the
>   structure of your app by exploring its content. **Continue showing the
>   drawer upon subsequent launches until the user actively expands the
>   navigation drawer manually. Once you know that the user understands
>   how to open the drawer, launch the app with the navigation drawer
>   closed.**
>
> [...]
>
> #### Give the user a quick peek
>
> **If the user touches the very left edge of the screen (within 20 dp from the left), have the drawer peek out as soon as the finger makes
>   contact with the display.** This promotes accidental discovery and
>   provides richer feedback.

Also, a `ProgressDialog` should **only be used for interaction-blocking background work**. This includes, for example, Loggin into a service. Loading data to show on the activity should be visualized in a more subliminal way.

If you're using an ActionBar, you can use the indeterminate ProgressBar in the AcionBar, as discussed here: [Showing indeterminate progress in Sherlock Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542103/showing-indeterminate-progress-in-sherlock-action-bar)

Otherwise, use a simple indeterminate ProgressBar and a "loading.."-text as a placeholder on the activity.

This way, your user sees that the app is loading data in the background, but he is also free to move to another Activity (in which case loading should continue, finish and be available when he comes back. Easily implemented with [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)).

Comment: I agree with everything Lukas says. If you have no UI to show while loading the data put the Spinner and "Loading" text in the center of the activity. Then open the drawer to show it to them. I would guess by the time they close it you'll be done loading and give the user a great experience. I posted here for how to do this will sexy animation http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883622/772428.

Though I do recommend trying to show your user some UI if at all possible. The longer the app takes to load the more likely the user will quit out...